# How to run a docker volume mount as a python subprocess?

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, docker-volume

I am trying to run a docker container, specifically `openalpr` found here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/openalpr/openalpr/

`docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/data:ro openalpr -c us plateTest1.jpg`

I am running into an error in python when trying to run this command as a subprocess:

import subprocess

**app.py**

```
result = subprocess.run(['docker', 'run', '-it', '--rm', '-v pwd:/data:ro', 'openalpr', '-c us', 'plateTest1.jpg'], capture_output=True)
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
(base) mac@macs-MBP lpr % python openalpr_test.py
b''
b'docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: \' pwd:data:ro\': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: \'data\' mount path must be absolute.\nSee \'docker run --help\'.\n'
```

I am assuming this has to do with escaping slashes?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `subprocess.run([...])`, you are responsible for breaking the command into "words".  There is no further processing here; everything gets passed on *exactly* as you have it.

In particular, when you

```py
subprocess.run([..., '-v pwd:/data:ro', ...])
```

The argument passed is exactly `-v pwd...` including the space in the single argument.  Docker sees a `-v` argument and parses the rest of this "word" as a volume specification, breaking it on colons, so mounting a named volume (with a leading space) `pwd` on container path `/data` in read-only mode.  Since (space) `pwd` isn't a valid volume name, you get this error.

You can break this into two separate words to disambiguate this, or remove the intermediate space.

```
subprocess.run([..., '-v', 'pwd:/data:ro', ...])
subprocess.run([..., '-vpwd:/data:ro', ...])
```

(In general it's better to avoid launching things as subprocesses if there is a native library or SDK that has the same functionality.  You might try to run this process using the [Docker Python SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/#python-sdk) instead.  Remember that it's very easy to use a `docker run` command to root the entire host: be very careful about what you're launching and how command lines are processed.)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the way I laid it out but this seems to work:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess

command='''
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/data:ro openalpr -c us plateTest1.jpg
'''
process=Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result=process.communicate()
print(result)
```